# How to host a serious discussion on a complex economic subtopic like President Trump's trade policy

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Paul Krugman will try to answer questions submitted to a NY times Facebook page in his opinion column.   See https://business.facebook.com/nytopinion/posts/2097908026890809 .
 Already many subsidiary intelligent questions have been posted as comments.    This appears as a discussion worthy of, basically an online open, lightly moderated discussion/course, which might vastly overflow The NY Times Facebook page.     Stackexchange seems to have a good evolvable design structure for this.    The questions do not necessarily appear worthy of their own Stack, (e.g. like math or economics).     Should it just start as one giant question and evolve from there?     Are there substacks in SE?    Suggestions?
Thanks, -sg

Comment: You want a BBS which operates using a thread structure similar to what Usenet had.  There are not many of those nowadays, so you'd probably need to host your own.

Answer (score 12):

We don't do discussions. It literally says so on the tin, or at least the [help centre under don't ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

It also says

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.

Which is what you're after.

> However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK

Well, OK, this would work but you'd have other people answering - unless Mr Krugman is a avid SE user (granted we got [John Carmack explaining something he tweeted on Super User once](https://superuser.com/questions/419070/transatlantic-ping-faster-than-sending-a-pixel-to-the-screen)) - but essentially this would be a way to formulate a question.

Polling for questions for that won't work in our model. If you want to try out a question to ask there *maybe* the appropriate stack would work.

From what I read though, this isn't really something that would fit into the SE model at all.